# Java Serialization save object in files

Tags: java, serialization

In java when serializing objects

```
FileOutputStream fileOut =
            new FileOutputStream("src/employee.ser");
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
    out.writeObject(em);
    out.close();
    fileOut.close();
```

Can we use any kind of extensions `.bin`,`.txt`as output file. why `.ser`is most prefereable?

Comment: You can use any extension you want.

Comment: Technically you could use any extension you wish, but .ser is probably preferable because then you know it is a serialized class. Just like you have .java files for source code files, those could be .txt too with the same context

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't spent a lot of time on linux. extensions mean nothing.

Comment: And, your question is more or less why extensions exist. The wikipedia article on them is quite long. Short answer: metadata.

Comment: Don't call it .txt. It isn't a text file.

Comment: @keyser now i found the reasons why those extensions are exist. i consider this as knowledge learned from these downvotes

Answer (score 3):

.ser is a shorthand from `Serializable` and the common 3 letter file extension. You can use any other extension you like or no extension altogether. The file will be created with no problem. **Test it**. After you test it and demonstrate to yourself this is possible, I would recommend defining the proper extension for the generated files, or just keep using ser since it's common Serialized binary data for Java developers.

Imagine you use txt as extension rather than ser or a custom extension. Another non-developer user of the PC *accidentally* enters to the folder containing your binary data file with a txt extension (probably on a Windows or Mac environment and hardly but not impossible on Linux :) ) and opens it and see gibberish because, after all, is serialized data. This user may do nothing for seeing gibberish or may think the file is corrupted and deletes it. IMO this is why it would be better to use a non-common extension for your files containing binary data.

Note: you can open any file with almost any program despite its extension and see it choke for not recognizing the format or displaying gibberish, but that's outside of the question.